# C# Interface containing a property with an enum type

Tags: c#, properties, enums

Trying to create an interface do the following which is not allowed any suggestions on how to resolve.

```
interface IMessages
{
    enum MessageItems { 
        Processing, 
        Completed, 
        Error 
    }

    MessageItems MessageVerification { set; }
    MessageItems MessageCreteUpload { set; }
    MessageItems MessageUploading { set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only [nest types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx) inside of classes or structs, not inside of interfaces.

Thus, you need to define the `enum` outside of the `interface`:

```
enum MessageItems { 
    Processing, 
    Completed, 
    Error 
}

interface IMessages
{
    MessageItems MessageVerification { set; }
    MessageItems MessageCreteUpload { set; }
    MessageItems MessageUploading { set; }
}
```

Comment: Was just going to post that. I generally put my enums in their own .cs files.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the `enum` outside of the `interface`:

```
 enum MessageItems { 
        Processing, 
        Completed, 
        Error 
    }

    interface IMessages
    {
        MessageItems MessageVerification { set; }
        MessageItems MessageCreteUpload { set; }
        MessageItems MessageUploading { set; }
    }
```

An interface contains only the signatures of methods, properties, events or indexers. A class or struct that implements the interface must implement the members of the interface that are specified in the interface definition.